# Intersection of line of a triangle with another line passing through opposite vertex and circumcenter

Tags: metapost

I have following code:

```
      pair a; pair b; pair c;
      pickup pencircle scaled 0.2pt;
      a = (0, 4cm); b = (-2cm, 0); c = (1cm, 0);
      draw a -- b -- c -- cycle;
      pair p; pair q; pair r; pair d; pair m; pair n;
      p = whatever[b, c]; a - p = whatever * (b - c) rotated 90;
      q = whatever[c, a]; b - q = whatever * (c - a) rotated 90;
      r = whatever[a, b]; c - r = whatever * (a -b) rotated 90;
      d = whatever[a, p] = whatever[b, q]; % orthocenter
      n = 1/4(a + b + c + d); % remarkably...
      m = d rotatedabout(n, 180); % M is also the circumcentre
      path circumcircle;
      circumcircle = fullcircle scaled 2 abs(m - a) shifted m;
      draw circumcircle;
      pair l;
      pickup pencircle scaled 2pt;
      drawdot m;
      pickup pencircle scaled 0.2pt;
      %draw a -- ((a -- m) intersectionpoint (b -- c));
```

I can compute circumcenter and it works. But the last commented line when uncommented tells me that paths do not intersect. Is it the case that `AM` is not extended for intersection calculation with BC? I think that I can manage that with `shifted` keyword but do not know how. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change the last line to following:

```
draw a -- (a -- (a - 100(a - m))) intersectionpoint (b -- c);
```

and get the line. It seems that line needs to be extended for `intersectionpoint` to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the same style as your earlier code, you can also do

```
pair q ; q = whatever[a,m] = whatever[b,c] ;
draw a -- q ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am a novice in Metapost.